# How to parallel run the function executeAsyncScript in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing

I am using selenium on nodeJS and I want to open X chrome instances / tabs and for each tab to run a script by the webdriver function - executeAsyncScript (because this is how I know the function was finished) is there any way to run these scripts togeter for each tab , because it seems that even if I call executeAsyncScript few times by loop it will still run one by one and not all tabs / chrome instance together.

```
  startProccess(null  , {enviornemt : "staging"});
function startProccess(err,result){
    console.log("started proccess");
    baseUrl = ENV_MAP[result.enviornemt] || ENV_MAP["local"];
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    openTabsForTests();
}

function openTabsForTests(){
    console.log("start to opened tabs");
    driver.executeAsyncScript(openNewTabCommand,TABS_COUNT - 1).then(function(data){
        setTimeout(function(){
            setTestsForRun();
        },1000);

    });
}

function setTestsForRun(){
    console.log("start to set tests");
    tabs = driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(tabs){
        console.log(tabs);
        cleanTabs = tabs;

        setTimeout(function(){
            startTestsRun();
        },1000);

    });

}
function startTestsRun(){

    console.log(cleanTabs);
    for(var i = 0 ; i< cleanTabs.length ; i++){
        var tab = cleanTabs[i];
        var index = i;
        driver.switchTo().window(tab);
        driver.executeAsyncScript(functionToRun,index,baseUrl).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    }
}
var functionToRun = async function(){
    var testCounter = 0;
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var currentIndex = arguments[0];
    var baseUrl = arguments[1];
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(currentIndex);
    },6000)


}
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Comment: Updated @marcel